D3 Graph should extend when currentStepIndex is triggerd and not rerendered
im trying to get in touch with the D3 library in my React project and so far so good. But i have one problem: i want to animate a graph/line step by step as defined in the filteredData depending on the CurrentStepIndex, which is triggerd by the Scrollama Library with .
useEffect(() => {
    const svg = d3.select(svgRef.current).select("svg").remove();


    const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
      const entry = entries[0];
      setMyGraphIsVisible(entry.isIntersecting);
      console.log(myGraphIsVisible);
    });

    observer.observe(svgRef.current);

    const svgContainer = d3
      .select(svgRef.current)
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`); //svg sits nice and coozy in the container

    const tooltip = svgContainer
      .append("foreignObject")
      .attr("class", "tooltip")
      .style("display", "none") // Tooltip zunächst ausblenden
      .attr("width", 80) // Breite des Tooltip-Bereichs
      .attr("height", 60); // Höhe des Tooltip-Bereichs

    const tooltipContent = tooltip
      .append("xhtml:div")
      .attr("class", "tooltip-content") // Klasse für Styling-Zwecke
      .style("background-color", "steelblue")
      .style("color", "white")
      .style("border-radius", "5px")
      .style("font-size", "12px");

    
    const x = d3
      .scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, d3.max(data2, (d) => d.year)])
      .range([0, width]);

    const y = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 100]).range([height, 0]);

    
    svgContainer
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height})`)
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(9).tickFormat(d3.format("d")));

    
    svgContainer.append("g").call(d3.axisLeft(y)).attr("class", "y-axis");

    
    svgContainer
      .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 0 - margin.left)
      .attr("x", 0 - height / 2)
      .attr("dy", "1em")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .style("font-size", "14px")
      .style("fill", "#777")
      .style("font-family", "sans-serif")
      .text("Erwerbsquote in %");

    

    svgContainer
      .append("text")
      .attr("class", "source-credit")
      .attr("x", width - 300)
      .attr("y", height + margin.bottom)
      .style("font-size", "9px")
      .style("font-family", "sans-serif")
      .style("fill", "#777")
      .text("Quelle: https://doku.iab.de/kurzber/2024/kb2024-10.pdf");

   
    svgContainer
      .selectAll("xGrid")
      .data(x.ticks().slice(1))
      .join("line")
      .attr("x1", (d) => x(d))
      .attr("x2", (d) => x(d))
      .attr("y1", 0)
      .attr("y2", height)
      .attr("stroke", "#e0e0e0")
      .attr("stroke-width", 0.1);

    // Add horizontal gridlines
    svgContainer
      .selectAll("yGrid")
      .data(y.ticks().slice(1))
      .join("line")
      .attr("x1", 0)
      .attr("x2", width)
      .attr("y1", (d) => y(d))
      .attr("y2", (d) => y(d))
      .attr("stroke", "#e0e0e0")
      .attr("stroke-width", 0.1);

   
    const line = d3
      .line()
      .x((d) => x(d.year))
      .y((d) => y(d.number));

   

    const filteredData =
      currentStepIndex === 1
        ? data2.slice(0, 4)
        : currentStepIndex === 2
        ? data2.slice(0, 7)
        : currentStepIndex === 3
        ? data2.slice(0, 9)
        : data2.slice(0, 0);

    const path = svgContainer
      .append("path")
      .datum(filteredData)
      .attr("fill", "none")
      .attr("stroke", "yellow")
      .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
      .attr("d", line);

    
    const totalLength = path.node().getTotalLength();
    path
      .attr("stroke-dasharray", totalLength)
      .attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength)
      .transition()
      .duration(2000)
      .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0);

    svg.selectAll("rect").remove(); // Remove any existing rectangles
    if (currentStepIndex === 4) {
      svgContainer
        .append("path")
        .datum(data2)
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("stroke", "yellow")
        .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
        .attr("d", line);

      const path2 = svgContainer
        .append("path")
        .datum(data3)
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("stroke", "white")
        .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
        .attr("d", line);

      const totalLength2 = path2.node().getTotalLength();

      path2
        .attr("stroke-dasharray", totalLength2)
        .attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength2)
        .transition()
        .duration(2000)
        .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0);
    }
    });

  }, [myGraphIsVisible, currentStepIndex]);

Data:
  const data2 = [
    { year: 0, number: 0 },
    { year: 1, number: 9 },
    { year: 2, number: 26 },
    { year: 3, number: 44 },
    { year: 4, number: 51 },
    { year: 5, number: 60 },
    { year: 6, number: 70 },
    { year: 7, number: 75 },
    { year: 8, number: 86 },
  ];

  const data3 = [
    { year: 0, number: 77.6 },
    { year: 1, number: 77.7 },
    { year: 2, number: 77.8 },
    { year: 3, number: 77.7 },
    { year: 4, number: 78.0 },
    { year: 5, number: 78.9 },
    { year: 6, number: 79.6 },
    { year: 7, number: 80.5 },
    { year: 8, number: 79.0 },
  ];

I know its saying in the first line
const svg = d3.select(svgRef.current).select("svg").remove();
which cause the issue, but if i get rid of this line it will render each Step a new SVG.
I tried different things, like an if clause where im asking if there is an existing SVG, but then my SVG is not working properly, like  "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'empty')"
Any suggestion to solve this Problem?
Thanks in Advance!
